# Go import file from another directory

Tags: go

I'm trying to import `utility` into `github_events.go`.

`utility.go` is placed under `services` directory.

`utility.go` looks like this:

```
package utility

import (
    "os"
    "regexp"
)
```

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

This is how import from `github_events.go`

```
import (
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"io/ioutil"
"net/http"
"sync"
"time"
"sort"

"github-app/services/utility"
)
```

I also tried with an alias `utility "github-app/services/utility"`

But I get the following error `could not import github-app/services/utility (no required module provides package "github-app/services/utility")compilerBrokenImport`

My `go.mod` file:

```
    module github-app
    go 1.18
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yoni you cannot import files in Go. **In Go ONLY packages can be imported**. Import the package `services` and use whatever is in file `utility.go` by qualifying it with the package name of the `services` package. And make sure to export whatever you want to use outside of the package in which it is declared.

Comment: @mkopriva correct. I meant importing a package. I've updated my question with the content of `utility`
(i'm a newbie to Go, so sorry for the mixup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import "github-app/services" and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work.
But don't I need to mention the exact package name?

Comment: You cannot have two files in one folder having two different packages.

Comment: You don't have to, but keep in mind that your current design is against convention. The convention is that the package name should generally match the directory's name. And also keep in mind that only ONE package can be at the root of a single directory, in other words you cannot have a second file in services directory, e.g. `helpers.go`, with `package helpers` as the first line, that is simply NOT allowed, all files in that directory need to have `package utility`, or, ideally, `package services`.

Comment: @mkopriva thx for the info. I've fix my code to follow this convention.